# translation from c to mips

Tags: c, mips

Can you help me to translate this piece of code from c to mips? I have ane exam the next week but i cant do this part, its very hard to me :(
Here its the code:

```
int A[4] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int B[4] = { 1, 1, 2, 3 };
int C[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

void
main()
{
    int actualizacion = 1;

    updateValues(4);
    actualizacion = actualizacion + 1;
}

void
updateValues(int var)
{

    switch (var) {
    case 4:
        do {
            var = var - 1;
            A[var] = B[var] - C[var];
        } while (var != 0);
        break;

    default:
        var = var * 2;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A few things: All values of the `A` array are replaced, so why have an initializer for `A` at all? In `main`, `actualizacion` is incremented but nothing is done with the value. In `updateValues`, if `var` is _not_ 4, `var` is doubled but nothing is done with the value [because it is an argument and is, therefore, function scoped--the value disappears upon return]. You don't print any values, so how can you check the results? `C` is zeroes, so the result in `A` will be just `B`. What is your environment (e.g. `spim`, `mars`, etc.)?

Comment: This code hasnt sense, its only an exercise to translate to mips, dont try to find the sense of the code i only need to know how is the translation, ty btw :)

Comment: Sure: Compile it on a MIPS compiler and look at the resulting assembly output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which IDE you're using (e.g. `spim`, `mips`, etc.). So, I used `mars`.

In C, when you index into an array, the compiler computes the offset based on the size [in bytes] of the element (e.g. for an `int`, this is 4). So, if the code was:

```
x = C[var]
```

The "effective" code would be:

```
x = *(int *) (((char *) C) + (var * 4));
```

In assembler, we have to do the same thing.

Here's the code with annotations:

```
    .data
A:  .word   2, 3, 4, 5
B:  .word   1, 1, 2, 3
C:  .word   0, 0, 0, 0

    .text
    .globl  main
# s0 -- actualizacion
main:
    li      $s0,1                   # actualizacion = 1

    li      $a0,4
    jal     updateValues

    addi    $s0,$s0,1               # actualizacion += 1

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

    .globl  updateValues
# a0 -- var (array index)
# t0 -- var << 2 (byte offset)
# t1 -- array address
# t2 -- B value
# t3 -- C value
updateValues:
    li      $t0,4
    bne     $a0,$t0,update_default

update_loop:
    addi    $a0,$a0,-1              # var -= 1
    sll     $t0,$a0,2               # convert index into byte offset

    la      $t1,B                   # base address of B
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t0             # add in byte offset
    lw      $t2,0($t1)              # load value

    la      $t1,C                   # base address of C
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t0             # add in byte offset
    lw      $t3,0($t1)              # load value

    sub     $t2,$t2,$t3             # B - C

    la      $t1,A                   # base address of A
    addu    $t1,$t1,$t0             # add in byte offset
    sw      $t2,0($t1)              # store value

    bnez    $a0,update_loop         # loop until var == 0
    b       update_exit

update_default:
    li      $t0,2
    mul     $a0,$a0,$t0             # var = var * 2

update_exit:
    jr      $ra                     # return
```